# How do i mock completable Future's supplyAsync methods response?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, java-8, completable-future

```
public class Test {
    public Obj func() {
        CompletableFuture<Obj> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new ContextSupplier<Obj> {
            public Obj onGet() {
               return otherClass.giveMeObj("X", "Y");
            }
        });
        // some business logic
        return completableFuture.get();
    }
}

class Obj {
    String s;
}
```

In the above snippet after submitting the task to completable future i have some non trivial business logic and then i return back the task's response, from completable future.
Is there a way i can mock CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() methods response.

Comment: Do I understand you right? You want to mock this part `CompletableFuture<Obj> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new ContextSupplier<Obj> {
            public Obj onGet() {
               return otherClass.giveMeObj("X", "Y");
            }
        });
` away ?

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what i want to mock.

Comment: How about just: mocking `otherClass` and stubbing `giveMeObj(...)` (with a little delay, if you like)? (so: *not* mocking `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` at all!;)

Answer (score 1):

Just define a class let say Example

```
public class Example {
   CompletableFuture<Obj> func(ContextSupplier<Obj> supplier) {
       <put code from your snippet here> 
   }
}
```

then mock this class e. g. with Mockito

```
Example exampleMock = mock(Example.class);
when(exampleMock.func(any(Class.class))).thenReturn( <put code for your mock here> );
```

Comment: Is there a way we can mock without moving to a new class?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to mock static methods with mockito, probably you could look at powermock https://github.com/powermock/powermock and find out whether it's possible with it.

Comment: not sure how this answer is related to future supplyasync mock ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether this can help you, but you don't need to mock `CompletableFuture supplyAsync()` method. You just mock your Task which you are submitting to supplyAsync. Then that result can be captured by `thenAccept()` method.

Recently I encountered such requirement and I did it like below:

1. Java code which I wanted to Mock:

   ```
   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(attributeUpdateTask::call).thenAccept(result->{  
         String status = (String)result[0]; //result of call method, in my case it was in object[] format   
       .............
       ...........
     }
   ```
2. Test case code:

   ```
   @Test public void testUploadUpdatedValueFileNOK(){
          Object[] response = new Object[3]; 
          response[0] = "KO";  
          when(attributeUpdateTask.call()).thenReturn(response);
    }
   ```